# What is this terrible place?

Tags: riddle, word

> Cross me, and you'll never return.
> Play with me, and you'll never see the dawn.
> Renew me, and I'll give you Hell.
> Yet don't worry, for as much as you pursue me,
> You'll never reach me.
>
> **Who am I?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Horizon

Cross me, and you'll never return.

> I think this refers to the [horizon of a black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon), beyond from which you cannot return if you cross.

Play with me, and you'll never see the dawn.

> I think this refers to [Horizon Zero Dawn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon_Zero_Dawn), which is a game you can play

Renew me, and I'll give you Hell.

> Thanks to Stiv from the help in the comments, I think this refers to [New Horizons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Horizons) which was a spacecraft whose primary mission was to perform a flyby study of the Pluto system, and [Pluto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto_(mythology)) was the ruler of the underworld in classical mythology.
>  **Original Guess:** I think this refers to [There Is a Hell Believe Me I've Seen It. There Is a Heaven Let's Keep It a Secret.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_Is_a_Hell_Believe_Me_I%27ve_Seen_It._There_Is_a_Heaven_Let%27s_Keep_It_a_Secret.) which is an album by *Bring Me The Horizon*

Yet don't worry, for as much as you pursue me,
You'll never reach me.

> Even when you chase the horizon, it moves further away from you.

Comment: I like this, I think you're likely pretty much there +1 I just remain to be fully convinced about the 'Renew me' line - to me it's almost a combination of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Horizons) (which fits the word) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Horizon_(film)) (which fits a horror context of Hell). Is there another film that might provide a suitable quote?

Comment: @Stiv, yes, I think you're right, there must be a better fit.

Comment: One thought - the first link I suggested above might show you ('give you') [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hell_(crater))... possibly?

Comment: @Stiv Ooh, I think I may have found a slightly better fit,

Comment: Ah, that's a nicer fit! I also accidentally happened upon [this story](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/astronomers-discover-hell-planet-k2-141b-rock-rain-lava-oceans/) while thinking about this, which is pretty cool. Anyway, this looks like a **solid** answer now :)

Comment: @Stiv, thanks for the help!

Comment: Well done, this is indeed the correct answer and reasons :)

Comment: Why is this a Terrible place?  In a general context the answer is not considered Terrible. Just curious.

Comment: @DrD Actually it isn't so, but the riddle describes it as a terrible place.

Comment: It could also be a "horrible zone"...

Answer (score 2):

The place could be

> The Heaven

Cross me, and you'll never return.

> You are dead, you can't return to the Earth

Play with me, and you'll never see the dawn.

> I guess that in Heaven it's always sunny. You probably don't even need to sleep.

Renew me, and I'll give you Hell.

> It could be "renew me" as "replace me with something else"

Yet don't worry, for as much as you pursue me,
You'll never reach me.

> I guess it's a sin to crave the Heaven. To deserve this terrible place, you have to be unselfishly good and kind.