# The Final Straw

Tags: riddle, word

Inspired by [this riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107054/what-is-this-terrible-place/)

> Cross me and you'll never return.
> Play with me and company I burn.
> Split me and a symbol I stroke.
> In all, I'm what P.W. spoke.

**Who/What am I?**
**The answer is a seven-letter word.**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think this final straw is the

> **Rubicon**

Cross me and you'll never return.

> Crossing the Rubicon means to pass a point of no return - from Caesar's [crossing the Rubicon river](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_the_Rubicon) from Gaul to Italy.

Play with me and company I burn.

> **Co. I burn** is an anagram of rubicon.

Split me and a symbol I stroke.

> **Rub icon** - stroke a symbol.

In all, I'm what P.W. spoke.

> P.W. Botha gave what is known as the [Rubicon speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubicon_speech) in 1985, where he stated the South African government would not reform regardless of the consequences.

Comment: Well done Tom! Perfect answer.